# How to change background color with animation in react-native viewpager?

Tags: react-native, animation, android-viewpager

I'm using rn-viewpager in react native and there is an example [here](https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager#integrate-into-your-app)
but how can I use animation in it like [this app](https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager/blob/master/imgs/dotIndicator.gif)?

Comment: By default, it is not coming?

Comment: No, I want the animation of changing color be like that gif.

Comment: Color depends on scroll value ?